# Snakemake: Exchanging variables

Tags: snakemake

I have some ONT sequencing runs that have been basecalled on the MINIT. As such, when I demultiplex with guppy_barcoder, I get a directory of fastq files for each barcode. I want to use snakemake as a workflow manager to take these fastq files through our analyses, but this involves swapping the {barcode} for {sample} at some point.

```
BARCODE=['barcode01', 'barcode02', 'barcode03', 'barcode04']
SAMPLE=['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03', 'sample04']

rule all:
    input:
        directory(expand("Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed/{barcode}", barcode=BARCODE)), #guppy_barcoder
        expand("Sequencing_reads/gathered/{sample}_ONT.fastq", sample=SAMPLE), #getting all of the fastq files with the same barcode assigned to the correct sample


rule demultiplex:
    input:
        glob.glob("Sequencing_reads/fastq_pass/*fastq")
    output:
        directory(expand("Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed/{barcode}", barcode=BARCODE))
    shell:
        "guppy_barcoder --input_path Sequencing_reads/fastq_pass --save_path Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed -r "


rule gather:
    input:
        rules.demultiplex.output
    output:
        "Sequencing_reads/gathered/{sample}_ONT.fastq"
    shell:
        "cat Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed/{wildcards.barcode}/*fastq > {output.fastq} "
```

This does give me an error:

`RuleException in line 32 of /home/eriny/sandbox/ONT_unicycler_pipeline/ONT_pipeline.smk:
'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'barcode'`

But I actually think I'm missing something conceptually. I would like `rule gather` to be something like:

```
cat Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed/barcode01/*fastq > Sequencing_reads/gathered/sample01_ONT.fastq
```

I have tried setting up some dictionaries so that sample and barcode are given the same key, but my syntax must be broken.

I'm hoping to find a 1:1 way to map one variable name onto another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm hoping to find a 1:1 way to map one variable name onto another.

I think the sample to dictionary is a possibility combined with a lambda as input function to get the barcode assign to a sample. For example:

```
BARCODE=['barcode01', 'barcode02', 'barcode03', 'barcode04']
SAMPLE=['sample01', 'sample02', 'sample03', 'sample04']

sam2bar= dict(zip(SAMPLE, BARCODE))

rule all:
    input:
        expand("Sequencing_reads/gathered/{sample}_ONT.fastq", sample=SAMPLE), #getting all of the fastq files with the same barcode assigned to the correct sample

rule demultiplex:
    input:
        glob.glob("Sequencing_reads/fastq_pass/*fastq"),
    output:
        done= touch('demux.done'), # This signals that guppy has completed
    shell:
        "guppy_barcoder --input_path Sequencing_reads/fastq_pass --save_path Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed -r "


rule gather:
    input:
        done= 'demux.done',
        fastq= lambda wc: glob.glob("Sequencing_reads/demultiplexed/%s/*fastq" % sam2bar[wc.sample])
    output:
        fastq= "Sequencing_reads/gathered/{sample}_ONT.fastq"
    shell:
        "cat {input.fastq} > {output.fastq} "
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!